# ERROR(ORPSIM-16103): Invalid value when simulating AC sweep

Tags: bandpass-filter, pspice, orcad

I am trying to simulate a simple active band pass filter. When I run the simulation, I get the above stated error.I cant seem to figure out the issue:

[Circuit diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQHao.png)

[Simulation settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1crI.png)

[Output error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMr02.png)

- I verified the AC sweep settings - 0 to 10Meg logrithmic seems correct. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.